# What is difference between function(){} and ()=>{}

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am new to Javascript and was reading an article about the Javascript events and found that in the article the author used '()=>{}' instead of 'function(){}' for event handlers. So I want to know what is that and what is the difference between these two ?

```
//What is the difference between these two ?
element.onclick = ()=>{
    alert("Ok");
};

element.onclick = function(){
    alert("Ok");
};
```

Comment: No difference between them and it's about versions of JavaScript

Comment: @Namatullah : nope big difference especially concerning event handlers...